# Do Multiple Subprocesses Utilize Multiple Cores?

Tags: mac, terminal, unix, multi-core

I have a question and it's basically exploring some lazy ways to utilize all the cores on a machine.

Say I have program "./theprogram" which acts on a data set D, is "embarrassingly parallel", and takes a commandline argument j that carries out the program on a subset of its dataset determined by j.

Then suppose in my terminal I run the commands

```
./theprogram j1 &
./theprogram j2 &
./theprogram j3 &
. etc
. etc
. etc
./theprgoram jfinal &
```

Now I have spawned subprocesses for j1, j2, ... jfinal

My question: assuming I have modern-ish unix system (say the most recent Mac Os X running on a multicore chip)

Then will the processes be distributed across all the cores seperately? I.E. i'm taking advantage of ALL my cores?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes.

The operating system schedules tasks onto unused CPU cores. It knows when a core is unused because it just unscheduled a task from it.

Your processes will have a flag in its structures denoting whether it is waiting on input (disk, keyboard, mouse, and so on) and so if it is not waiting on any of those things then it is schedulable.

For every core the operating system will essentially run through its list of schedulable tasks and schedule them. The tasks will be given a slice of time on the core and then suspended again so that the OS can see if *other* processes need to run.

If no other processes need to run then yours will still be at the top of the list and get another go.

The natural effect is that, with a small management overhead, your CPU will be fully utilized, assuming none of your processes block each other or spend an embarrassing amount of time waiting on disk accesses.

You can test this with any multithreaded application with paralleisable data. Video encoding and data compression are two situations where this kind of parallelism pays off.

Handbrake is a CPU based video encoder (recently with GPU support as well) that could use as many CPU cores as you liked and would achieve a high level of speed boost by doing so. Many video encoders can make good use of multiple cores. x.264 and other encoders also support multiple threads.

7-Zip is a compression program that can also make use of multiple threads in its LZMA2 algorithm to speed up compression. Compression dictionary buildup is a reasonable shared process and once you have a dictionary the actual compression is "trivially" paralleisable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to multiprocess you have to pick the section of code that adheres to:

1. Can't be reliant on previous outcomes
2. Doesnt require being executed in a particular order
3. Wont return anything that will need to be accessed later in the code

So from what I hear if it follows that you should be able to use your multiple cores.